# obtener la posicion de una fila en GridView Devexpress, para deshabiltar boton editar

Tags: c#, devexpress

No se si alguien ha tenido este mismo problema.

Quiero deshabilitar y habilitar el boton editar de un gridview devexpres con la condición del valor de la columna área. Es decir si el usuario que ingreso pertenece al area de finanzas solo habilitar la fila de finanzas para que pueda editar solo su área, y las demás filas deben permanecer deshabilitadas.
Actualmente estoy recorriendo la columna area con un for, pero como puedo poner la condicion de que si area es finanzas la fila de la posicion de abajo del gridview se deshabilite. Agradeceria cualquier comentario

protected void gridapprovals_HtmlRowPrepared(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableRowEventArgs e)
{

```
        for (int i = 0; i < gridapprovals.VisibleRowCount; i++)
        {
        
            object Row = gridapprovals.GetRow(i);
            string var = ((System.Data.DataRowView)(Row)).Row.ItemArray[1].ToString();

            //if (e.RowType != GridViewRowType.Data) return;
            //string plevel1 = Convert.ToString(e.GetValue("Area"));


            //var s = (e.VisibleIndex == 1);

            if (var == txtareafirmantes.Text)
            {
                //var sa = e.VisibleIndex == 2;
                //var s1 = e.VisibleIndex == 1;

                if (e.VisibleIndex == 0)
                    e.Row.Enabled = false;

               
                if (e.VisibleIndex == 1)
                    e.Row.Enabled = true;

                if (e.VisibleIndex == 2 )

                    e.Row.Enabled = true;
                
                
                  

                
                return;
            }
          }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como cargas la grilla? porque haces eso, en lugar de pasarle una clase que tenga esa propiedad y la aplique a la fila?

Comment: Hola gbianchi el grid se carga por su evento databinding, asi esta cargado. Alguna idea de como se puede hacer el detalle que tengo?.. Saludos amigo

Comment: o sea, le estas bindeando un objeto... no podes bindear esa propiedad tambien? no tengo ni idea como funciona ese control, pero los controles devexpress suelen ser versatiles...